# Preventing move of non-copyable struct

Tags: rust

I have the following:

```
struct User {
    username: String,
}

fn test(user: User) -> Result<(), Error> {
    Ok(())
}

fn query(user: &User) -> Result<(), Error> {
    test(*user)
}

fn main() {
    let user = User {username: "test".to_string()};
    query(&user);
    println!("user: {:?}", user.username);
}
```

Apologies for the maybe basic question:

Ideally, I'd like for `query` to borrow `user`, and return ownership to `main`. `User` intentionally does not implement the `Copy` trait. I cannot `move` the ownership because I'd like for `user` to continue to be used later in `main`. I cannot change the type signature of `test`.

When I run this code, I see the following error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*user` which is behind a shared reference
  --> experimental/main.rs:32:10
   |
32 |     test(*user)
   |          ^^^^^ move occurs because `*user` has type `User`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I obviously can't call `query(user)` (without borrowing), which represents a move of ownership into `query`.

Is it possible for `query` to borrow `user` in a way that I can call `test` and still allow `main` to have ownership?

Comment: Short answer: No, as `test` expects ownership of `user` which `query` cannot provide unless it itself takes ownership of `user`.

Comment: You cannot have your cake and eat it too (i.e. `query` cannot leave the ownership at `main` and give it to `test` at the same time. Only one place can have the ownership at any given time.) Maybe `std::rc::Rc` can help you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for query to borrow user in a way that I can call test and still allow main to have ownership?

`query` can explicitly duplicate the structure and that's about it:

```py
fn query(User { username }: &User) -> Result<(), Error> {
    test(User { username: username.to_string() })
}
```

Incidentally, `User` *can not* implement `Copy`, as `String` is not `Copy` (since it's not a trivial value). It *could*, and probably should, implenent `Clone`.

Comment: While calling `to_string` on a `String` is one way to clone it. I would not consider that idiomatic: just call `clone`. And it does look like the OP just wants to make `User` `Clone` too.

Comment: "While calling to_string on a String is one way to clone it." semantically I don't want to clone it here, I want an owned string from a borrowed one. "And it does look like the OP just wants to make User Clone too." yes, hence the last paragraph.